# Table of integrals for dimensional regularization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, integration, dimensional-regularization

Is there any reference (book or paper) that contains a list of integrals useful for dimensional regularization?

I would need it to approach integrals like these

$$
\int d^dx \frac{x^\mu}{|x|^{2d-4}}, \qquad \int d^dx \frac{(x-y)^\mu}{|x-y|^d |x-z|^{d-2}}.
$$

Any suggestion is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Have you tried the appendix of P&S?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Appendices of QFT textbooks usually have tables of DR integrals used through the textbook, for example in [Peskin and Schroeder](https://books.google.com/books/about/An_Introduction_To_Quantum_Field_Theory.html?id=EVeNNcslvX0C) Appendix A.4, and [Schwartz](https://schwartzqft.fas.harvard.edu/) Appendix B.
- For general one-loop integrals, there are easy to use computer packages like [Package-X](https://packagex.hepforge.org/) on Mathematica, that can deal with massive propagators.
- For higher loop calculations, [Mincer](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Eform/maindir/packages/mincer/mincer.html) is a tool that does massless three-loop calculations (written in FORM). Nice lecture on Mincer [here](https://www.nikhef.nl/%7Eform/maindir/courses/capp2021/mincer.pdf).
  If you want to understand the technology behind higher-loop calculations, [Grozin](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ph/0307297) has a lecture notes on multiloop calculations that details the integration-by-parts methods.
- For a more in-depth look into Dimensional Regularization, [Collins](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/renormalization/6EA5EEEBB9A02190F7C805856244181B) book on renormalisation contains a lot of details. Chapter 4 in particular introduces an axiomatic approach, which (for me) clarified a lot of the mathematical details, and what manipulations are allowed.

Comment: Thanks for this list. However, your last link to Collins' book is unusable (ends up on a login page, no way to go past it).

Comment: Sorry, hopefully the link is fine now

Comment: It is, thank you. :-)

Comment: Thank you very much for this list of resources :^)